# get value of an attribute after matching value of another attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I'm completely new to jQuery/javascript and have been beating my head against this simple task for days.

I want to find a meta element in a page with attribute `property="og:title"`, and then get the value of the attribute `"content"`, e.g.:

`<meta property="og:title" content="Leaders Say Progress Made in Dealing With Euro Crisis"/>`

so I want to get the text "Leaders Say Progress Made in Dealing With Euro Crisis", and perhaps write it within in the page or pass it to another function.

How would I get the value of the content attribute? I tried `.$("meta [property='og:title']")` but then I realized that would try to get the non-existent text element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content');
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('meta[property="og:title"]').each(function(){
   var contentVal = $(this).attr("content");
});
```

in case of multiple meta tags with same property

Answer (score 1):

`$("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content")`

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin :

#### http://code.google.com/p/wt-plugins/wiki/wtMeta

or you can try:

```
  $("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content")
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/NymkA/1/)

Comment: I couldn't use the plugin, looks like it only checks for 2 kinds of attributes.  It did help me understand the syntax though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code wasn't working was because your selector was wrong. You had a space between `meta` and `[property ..]`, there shouldn't be one.

If there is one meta tag:

```
var meta_content = $("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content');
writeToPage( meta_content ); // Pass to a function to change the DOM.
```

If there are more than one:

```
var meta_content = [];
$("meta[property='og:title']").each(function () {
  meta_content.push( $(this).attr('content');
});
writeToPage( meta_content );
```

Comment: thank you, I've been having a lot of trouble with the syntax. I'm now starting to figure it out...